# Submit form from loaded tab in Firefox Addon SDK?

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, sdk, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make a FF addon which could open new tab, load page with login form and submit this form. The main issue is that there a lot of additional parameters also must be sent. So I cannot simulate this POST-request exactly with XMLHttpRequest and content scripts. Instead of this I just want to get the form via DOMParser, set login and password in input fields and send it via form.submit(), but nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
const windowUtils = require("sdk/window/utils");
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var DOMPars = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
var gBrowser = windowUtils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getBrowser();
var newTab = gBrowser.addTab("https://some-page-url");
var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(newTab);
var contentdata = "";

newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
    contentdata = contentdata + newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    var dom = DOMPars.parseFromString(contentdata, "text/html");
    var login_form = dom.getElementsByName('login_form_name');

    if(typeof login_form !== "undefined"){
        dom.getElementsByName('user_login').value = 'user_login_here';
        dom.getElementsByName('user_pass').value = 'user_pass_here';
        login_form.submit();
    }
}, true);
```

Is it possible to do it in this way? Thanks!